# findMeetingTimes throws 500 error, code unchanged

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Our code started throwing the following error today, for a very simple findMeetingTimes request.
This is the error:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "{\"ClassName\":\"System.ArgumentNullException\",\"Message\":\"Value cannot be null.\",\"Data\":null,\"InnerException\":null,\"HelpURL\":null,\"StackTraceString\":\"   at System.String.Join(String separator, String[] value)\\r\\n   at Microsoft.Griffin.WebService.Calendar.Scheduling.DefaultController.<ExecuteWorkflow>d__53`2.MoveNext()\",\"RemoteStackTraceString\":null,\"RemoteStackIndex\":0,\"ExceptionMethod\":\"8\\nJoin\\nmscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\\nSystem.String\\nSystem.String Join(System.String, System.String[])\",\"HResult\":-2147467261,\"Source\":\"mscorlib\",\"WatsonBuckets\":null,\"ParamName\":\"value\"}",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "f9153038-b8e2-41a8-bba6-dad2a8cc3afa",
        "date": "2019-09-10T12:01:37"
    }
}
```

This is the POST request

```
{
"attendees": [{
    "emailAddress": {
        "address": "amy@domain.com"
    },
    "type": "required"
}],
"timeConstraint": {
    "timeslots": [{
        "start": {
            "dateTime": "2019-09-10T12:01:36",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "end": {
            "dateTime": "2019-09-17T12:01:36",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        }
    }]
},
"meetingDuration": "PT30M",
"maxCandidates": 4,
"minimumAttendeePercentage": 100
}
```

Anyone got an idea what might be causing this?

// Edit:
Some more testing revealed that this is still working with a bearer token from Microsoft Graph Explorer, but not our own token which generated from an AzureAD app registration. From what we understand the tokens should be both valid (and have been up until a few hours ago... Our token also works for other endpoints)

Our token data:

```
  {
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/0e7219f7-4c4d-47e7-b98a-7b9b9de02b80/",
  "iat": 1568152509,
  "nbf": 1568152509,
  "exp": 1568156409,
  "acct": 0,
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": "******",
  "amr": [
      "pwd",
      "mfa"
  ],
  "app_displayname": "Outlook Meetings for Jira",
  "appid": "fb930189-fe2c-4b11-b424-f576f7b371b3",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "family_name": "*******",
  "given_name": "*****",
  "ipaddr": "185.85.64.210",
  "name": "*****",
  "oid": "12ad9a79-78ae-424a-b6ef-a6ec78f69f3f",
  "platf": "3",
  "puid": "10033FFF8670ACD2",
  "scp": "Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared email offline_access User.Read User.ReadBasic.All",
  "signin_state": [
      "kmsi"
  ],
  "sub": "QsD80H0dBCYK4wttPZFIY1w_Pi5Ygbn9OwKuiNkNPXo",
  "tid": "0e7219f7-4c4d-****-b98a-7b9b9de02b80",
  "unique_name": "...@....com",
  "upn": "...@....com",
  "uti": "uzKz01rSV0SD1kTwBZJkAA",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "wids": [
      "62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10"
  ],
  "xms_tcdt": 1374053072
```

}

Comment: Alright, it seems the issue is actually that we currently only request "Calendar.ReadWrite.Shared" - which should be working according to the documentation. This leads to the issue above. You also need "Calendars.ReadWrite"....

Comment: You saved me man. Thanks a ton.

Comment: After applying this solution it has started working fine. But in case of guest users this is still not working. Can you help in this?

Comment: @YatendrasinhJoddha We'll try to reach out to Microsoft, this def. looks like a bug on their side...

Comment: We had discussion with them. We come to know that, there was an issue from their side. They have rolled out the update and now everything is working fine. I think you should also try with your older permissions. For me it has started working.

Comment: Thank you for posting the status of this issue.